# Unable to create a textclip in moviepy (imagemagick succesfully installed?) - got Utf8 Error

Tags: python, utf-8, moviepy

i got this error when using moviepy with "TextClip": 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 5: invalid start byte

Imagemagick and wand are (proper?) installed.
Does anybody knows a possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently moviePy expects non unicode strings (file `moviepy/video/VideoClip.py`, line 1095). the workaround for this would be to decode your unicode strings before passing them to the TextClip:

```
if isinstance(mytext, unicode):
    mytext = mytext.encode('latin1')
```

### EDIT

MoviePy expects UTF8 strings (non unicode), so the above becomes

```
if isinstance(mytext, unicode):
    mytext_str = mytext.encode('utf8')
```